# Could anyone explain me how to get rid of this white stripes?

Tags: css

[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpVou.png)

```
.albums_content_left button {

width: 160px;
height: 50px;
background-image: url("buttonbg.png");
background-position: top left;
border: 3px solid rgb(242,123,132);
font-family:'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
color: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
box-sizing: content-box;
transition: .4s;
letter-spacing: 1px;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 14px;
```

}

```
.albums_content_left button:hover {

background-position: right;
```

}

```
<section class="albums" id="albums">
    <p class="paragraph">Albums</p>
    <div class="albums_content">
        <div class="albums_content_left">
            <p>My albums</p>
            <p>I love photographing a multitude of places and subjects</p>
            <button>View Albums</button>
        </div>
        <div class="albums_content_right">   
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Im creating button with hover effect which makes move background image from left to right. But im seeing 2 white stripes which are like 0,5 px width nerby top and bottom border. Anyone?

Comment: Do add your HTML code too. That will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Adding:
border:none
has resolved the problem.